# Flow down tables with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive bootstrap table (1 tr and 3 td) and when it comes to xs devices I want them to flow down.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="maincontent">

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table"><tr><td>

<div class="thumbnail" id="tropthumb">
<img src="images/mainconimg/trophy.jpg" alt="trophies" id="mainconimg">
<div class="caption">
<h3 id="trop">Trophies</h3>
<p><a href="trophies.html" class="btn btn-primary" id = "btnview" role="button">View</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div class="thumbnail" id = "medalthumb">
<img src="images/mainconimg/medals.jpg" alt="trophies" id="mainconimg2">
<div class="caption">
<h3 id="medal">Medals</h3>
<p><a href="medals.html" class="btn btn-primary" id = "btnview2" role="button">View</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td>          
<div class="thumbnail" id = "souvnthumb">
<img src="images/mainconimg/souvn.jpg" alt="trophies" id="mainconimg3">
<div class="caption">
<h3 id="souvn">Souvenirs</h3>
<p><a href="souvenirs.html" class="btn btn-primary" id = "btnview3" role="button">View</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</td></tr></table>

</div>
</div>
```

**I have this table with single row and 3 td on it and each of td contains a thumbnail image. And when it comes to xs devices I want them to flow down like in the example picture please help me with this.

[this is what i wanted to look like when it comes to xs devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbpnA.jpg)

Comment: You will have to change your HTML for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `tables` for a specific purpose? Because if not, you can use the `grid` on Bootstrap.

e.g.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12"> "your image here" </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12"> "your image here" </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12"> "your image here" </div>
</div>
```

But you can omit the code `col-xs-12` because I think `col-md-4` automatically flows them down if you resize your screen.

Comment: Thanks ! It helped. It didn't come to my mind earlier.

Comment: Glad you find it useful, please mark it as answer :)